# How to set default value for Boolean, when using Builder Pattern in Lombok (Case of user not setting the particular value)?

Tags: java, spring, boolean, builder

Consider the following model:

```
class Student {
     private int id;
     private Boolean isPresent = Boolean.False;
}
```

Now if I build a student object using Builder pattern, while not setting the value for isPresent is 'null' and not 'false' as we have initialized.

```
Student model = Student.builder().id(10).build();
// model.isPresent is set as null instead of false
```

I want to know for this particular use case is there any way to set isPresent to false i.e initialize a Boolean variable when user does not sets the value in Builder pattern?
Please note I am **unable to use boolean** instead of 'Boolean' or **set value** of isPresent in builder.

Edit: I am using Lombok to implement builder pattern. I am using All args constructor and no args constructor and getter, setter methods.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you in control of this code or not? Because if the `Student` class is correct, then you're initializing it to `False` as desired. So, if using the builder leads to it being null, then the builder is overwriting that property. Fixing this is a simple matter of modifying the builder and/or student constructor appropriately--assuming you can modify the code. Perhaps if you provided a [mre] then someone could be of more help.

Comment: Hi I have added info and also shared in comments in your answer. Should I update the title for better explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about which of the two approaches you are using, so I am providing answer for both the below cases:

1. Are you implementing the Builder Pattern?
2. Are you using any framework which provides the builder pattern for you?

---

1. If you are implementing the builder pattern you can initialize inside the `StudentBuilder` class this way:

```
class Student {
    private final int id;
    private Boolean isPresent = Boolean.FALSE;

    Student(int id, Boolean isPresent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.isPresent = isPresent;
    }

    public static StudentBuilder builder() {
        return new StudentBuilder();
    }

    public static class StudentBuilder {
        private int id;
        private Boolean isPresent = Boolean.FALSE;

        StudentBuilder() {
        }

        public StudentBuilder id(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public StudentBuilder isPresent(Boolean isPresent) {
            this.isPresent = isPresent;
            return this;
        }

        public Student build() {
            return new Student(id, isPresent);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Student.StudentBuilder(id=" + this.id + ", isPresent=" + this.isPresent + ")";
        }
    }
```

---

2. if you are using any framework like Lombok for the builder pattern,

   You can replace the Boxed data type with primitive data types:

   ```
   class Student {
       private int id;
       private boolean isPresent;  //default is false.
   }
   ```

   That will also result in the `false`

---

Edit: Alternatively you can check for Null in the constructor and implement the logic by yourself.

Like:

```
@Getter
@Builder
class Student {
    private int id;
    private Boolean isPresent;

    private Student(int id, Boolean isPresent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.isPresent = isPresent;
        if (this.isPresent == null) {
            this.isPresent = false;
        }    
}
```

Note: When using the `builder` pattern you want to **make the object as immutable after the `build`**. So don't make the `setter` explicitly available, furthermore don't even allow the instantiation (make the constructor private).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using Lombok for the builder pattern. Also as I have mentioned due to constraints I can't use boolen, I have to use Boolean only.

Comment: Hi, @HargunSingh I have updated my answer, please verify if that is acceptable. it complies with the contraints.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to do this as its a complex model with many fields and uses. Isn't there any property in Lombok builder which stops this over ride from happening ?

Comment: @HargunSingh yes you can even make it simple. I have updated the answer. :) Checking in the constructor if it is null

Comment: @HargunSingh is this answer acceptable?

Comment: its a great answer but in my particular usecase due to some constraints I am not allowed to edit the setter of model. If existing setter could be modified or some property to stop this override could be used it will be the ideal answer. However if this is a constraint in Lombok, then I will mark this as the accepted answer. Thank you so much again for all your time and efforts!

Comment: @HargunSingh 1. You are not overriding the setters at all. 2. No, there is no such option through which you can override that functionality of Lombok. You can make your own annotation and add your custom implementation.

Comment: Thanks I will choose this as the accepted answer, learnt a lot! Hope it can help someone out in future

Answer (score 2):

The builder here will override the default value to null. So, you had to specify false/true when ever you build this object. This is the behavior of lambok builder.
The other work around for this would be to specify as below

```
@Builder.Default private Boolean optionalEndDate = false
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check out this property, its similar to what I was looking for!